# Unable to Load JSON File as Dictionary

Tags: python, json

I created a Login in System in Visual Studio code where User can create a new Account. This Information shall be stored in a JSON-File as Dict with Username as key and Password as value. Everything almost works so far except the JSON-File with dict won't load in Python and I don't know why.

```
import json

status = ""

def displayMenu():
    loadFile()
    print(users.keys())
    saveFile()
    status = input("Are you registered user? y/n? Press q to quit")
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()


def newUser():
    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in users:
        print("\nLogin name already exist!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw
        print("\nUser created\n")

def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
    else:
        print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")

def saveFile():
    with open('personal.json', 'a') as json_file:
        json.dump(users, json_file)

def loadFile():
    with open('personal.json', 'r') as json_file:
        users = json.load(json_file)

while status != "q":
    displayMenu()
```

Comment: This is something normally done using a database. But if you are doing this with a file storing a `JSON` representation of a dictionary, three things. (1) You must guard against simultaneous writing to the file by two separate processes, so look into file locking for function `saveFile`, for example package `filelock` from the `PyPI` repository. (2) You don't want to be opening the output file with flag `a` but rather with flag 'w' to replace the original contents, i.e. you don't want multiple back-to-back dictionaries, which is what you are getting. (3) Passwords should be encrypted.

Comment: Point 2 in my first comment (I ran over the size limit for a comment) is probable cause of your error.